# Segregate products in categories according to popularity

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I would like to segregate "out of style" items to go at the bottom of each category, all dependable on the popularity of the product or sold amount.

Basically, the most selling products to be at the top of the category.

Is there any easy way of doing it? What are the options?